# Slow data load with conversion from nvarchar to varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a table which has approximately 140 columns. The data for this table comes from a transactional system and many of the columns are Unicode.

I dump the daily load to my Staging database whose data type matches exactly with what the source system has.From Staging, I do some cleaning and load it to a Reports database. When loading from Staging to Reports database, I convert all the Unicode character data to String and then load it to reports database. This process takes an awful lot of time and I am trying to optimize this process (make the load times faster).

I use the Derived column transformation to convert all the Unicode Data to String data. Any suggestions here for me?

Comment: why not use unicode on teh reports db so you don;t have to convert the data?

Comment: This is where I get more confused. Will using NVARCHAR harm anything in any way? Say for example, query run time or the space occupied by the records?? Any performance advantage/disadvantage for using either NVARCHAR Or VARCHAR ???

Comment: What is the destination type (ole or ado.net) and settings (Fast load, load from variable, lock table, etc) for the Reports destination? Secondly, do you know where the bottleneck is? A quick experiment would be to replace the destination with a Row Count transformation. This will give you an estimate of how long it takes to get all of the data out of the source/staging system. Is that time is significantly different than time to write to Reports DB? Also, if you have all 140 conversions in a single derived column, split that out to multiple transforms for parallelization benefits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about if you cast your columns as varchar(size) on your source query?

Comment: Cant do that. The database that I pull from has a specific ODBC driver which does not support any SQL functions other than SELECT. I know thats strange, but thats what it is. I already tried CAST, but could not change anything due to drivers incapability.

Comment: not even inside the SSIS Sorce component? How are you running the query to get the data?

Comment: I connect to the source using the SSIS ADO.NET Source component. I have a DSN on the box that connects to the source system. I tried manipulating the source input/output data types, but the driver is so crooked that it bombs out.

Comment: Diego. Found a way to convert the data at source. I am going to implement that to see how the performance changes. Thanks for the tip!